# Voltage regulator question

Tags: capacitor, diodes, charger, device, 7805

I have made a portable device charger with a 5 volt voltage regulator(7805-TO220 package),a 9 volt battery and a few capacitors.The problem is,when I connect the charger to a certain device(whose original charger outputs 5 volts and 2A) and the device starts charging, after a few minutes,the image starts flashing and then it shuts down,then the start-up screen appears,then the screen turns black and so on a few times,then it shuts down completely and remains in this state.I connected the circuit to another device whose original charger outputs 5,1 volts and 700 mA and all works just fine.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYaxhR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Why does the first device behave this way?
I don'think it's about the voltage or current.
The 9 volt battery is a Varta High Energy model-6LP3146. 
EDIT:I noticed that when charging the second device,its battery drops after a while,whether discharging on its own or being discharged by my charger(I added a diode between the output pin of the regulator and the positive terminal of the device,so it's unlikely).

Comment: Provide details of the 9V battery.

Comment: Do you have enough cooling for the linear regulator (7805)? It may be hot and turn of.

Comment: No,I checked it every time.And it also has a heatsink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't mention what case style of 7805 you have. If i was guessing you are using a TO220. That case can only support up to 1A output current and even then requires substantial heat sinking to do so. Some 7805s had thermal protection and would shut down if overheating. Check the voltage to the device when it shuts down. Perhaps the voltage drops out.

Also you cryptically say that it's a 5v device. If i also had to guess it's a USB device. Some USB devices require that an identified is detected on the data lines to announce that the device is connected to a charger. For example my HTC phone charger shorts the data lines together. Also my Galaxy tab doesn't like my HTC charger because Samsung uses a different scheme to identify the charger.

Comment: Its original charger is not USB.

Answer (score 1):

They typical applications on [page 18 and 19 of the datasheet](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/LM/LM7805.pdf) show an input capacitor of 0.33uF and an output capacitor of 0.1uF. Your input is 300x larger and your output is 100x larger than the datasheet shows. I'm not sure if this is causing any issues.

This regulator also can't handle 2A output current, so it might be browning out. Also, a 9V battery [doesn't have too much capacity to start with](http://www.powerstream.com/9V-Alkaline-tests.htm), so it could also be dead. Bear in mind that terminal voltage under no-load conditions isn't the best way to measure capacity.

You should check terminal voltage under load to see if your battery is supplying the [7.5V minimum required for a 5V output](http://www.learnabout-electronics.org/PSU/psu23.php) - I would be this is why your device keeps shutting down.

Comment: FYI - [This figure](http://www.powerstream.com/z/9V-500mA-test.png) on the battery capacity page I linked shows that, at a discharge rate of 500mA, you'll hit the 7.5V cutoff voltage after you've discharged about 0.02Ah of capacity. At 0.5A, that means you hit the cutoff voltage in (0.02Ah/0.5A) = 0.04 hours, or about 2.4 minutes. It looks like, by their curves, no 9V battery could supply adequate supply voltage to keep the voltage regulator on after about 150 seconds of charging.

Comment: So you are saying that I'm consuming the battery for nothing?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking, but the way that you have setup your system I don't think you're getting much use from the battery.

Comment: Can you suggest what should I change to make it feasible?

Comment: Use a different battery or double up on your 9V batteries. The regulator handles up to 35V in, so you can put two 9V batteries in series and never have to worry about falling below the cutoff voltage until both batteries are dead.

Comment: But, even then, you will only get maybe 30 minutes or so of charging time.

Comment: I will replace the battery with 5 rechargeable batteries.They have different capacities and the lowest has 800mAh.They will be in series and equal 6 volts.Will they be better than the 9 V battery?

Comment: You should never [mix batteries](http://m.mentalfloss.com/article.php?id=57163) because different chemistries and capacities have different discharge-voltage curves. There's a fair chance for a battery to overheat and leak when it's the only good battery left in the pack. Why not just spend the 4 dollars on half a dozen new identical batteries?

Comment: Capacitors (which @Chuck says in his answer that they could be a problem) are not actually the issue here. Plenty of circuits like this use a whopping 470uF on out output and even 10000uF on input. The datasheet gives minimum values for the LM7805 to be stable. See also http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/192666/54580 on this matter.