# 7805 for 4-20mA current injector

Tags: current-source, constant-current, 7805, 4-20ma

I'm trying to setup a low cost current injector for testing certain I/O modules.
I found a rather simple design for a current source using 7805.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBP8q1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

So I tried making that and changed the resistances to match my requirement.
I have a 24 Volt source on the test rack, which powers the I/O modules as well.
Since this is  a low cost project, I used the same power supply and ended up with this. -->

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHaG5B.png)</sup>

This circuit worked perfectly when I tested it with a multimeter. It gave 3.6mA to 20.1 mA.

However, while testing with the I/O module, the current through the load (I/O module's internal resistance) never went above 15.6 mA. The I/O module has a floating ground and therefore an isolated current measuring setup.
But when I touch the heat sink, the current rose to 20.7mA
Thinking this might be due to the capacitance effect from my body, I added a capacitor between the input and GND(what I could find lying around in the workshop was a 35v 100uF).
Now I see that the output is in the range of 3.6mA to 20.8mA.

I am not literate enough to calculate the correct capacitance required or evaluate whether this setup is reliable.Please advise.

Comment: Try reading the data sheet for a 7805 - it will tell you that you need two capacitors to generally stabilize it.

Comment: The capacitor helped, probably (though not definitively) because the I/O modules picked up noise on the output differently than your multimeter. Other than that, see @i-chodera 's answer.

Comment: An 7805 has a rather large (and varying!) quiecent current. An LM317 is designed to be used in this configuration, and has a much lower (and much more stable!) quiecent current.

Comment: Most likely it's not happy with the source impedance of your power supply- it is typically stable with just an input capacitor. Try a 100nF capacitor from 7805 'in' to GND **within 10-20mm of the 7805**. As Wouter says, this is not ideal- the GND current (typically at least several mA) will change at least several percent just from warming up.

Answer (score 3):

The 7805 is a generic part, variants are made by lots of manufacturers, you should check the datasheet for the exact part and make you have used. Typically they recommend a 0.1uF capacitor between Out and GND and a 0.33uF capacitor between In and GND. These are **required** for stability. In practice, you will probably find that any values greater than these will work fine.

Comment: Indeed, at least Fairchild recommends caps, even when used as a constant current source https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/LM/LM7805.pdf (fig 10, p. 19). The LM317 datasheet omits caps when configured as current source. So overall probably even cheaper, never mind better performing in this role as @Wouter van Ooijen noted.